# Why doesn't my code produce output?

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to VHDL and I've just been messing around with Quartus II 9.0 and decided to make a register type component. I think my logic is right but I'm not getting any output when I run the simulation. I created a waveform to test possible situations (used node finder to list all inputs and output, generated the functional simulation netlist) but I do not get any output for Q. Not even the simple case when clr = 1 and all of Q should be set to 0.

```
library ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;

ENTITY Register32 IS PORT ( 
    d     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0); -- input.
    ld    : IN STD_LOGIC; -- load/enable.
    clr   : IN STD_LOGIC; -- async. clear.
    clk   : IN STD_LOGIC; -- clock.
    Q     : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 DOWNTO 0)); -- output.
END Register32;

ARCHITECTURE description OF Register32 IS
BEGIN

    process (clk) begin
        if (clr = '1') then
            Q <= (others => '0');
        else
            if (rising_edge(clk)) then
                if (ld = '1') then
                    Q <= d;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if; 
    end process;

END description;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `clr` is asynchronous, then it must be included in the process
sensitivity list, since update of `Q` should react immediately on changes to
`clr`.  Quartus II has probably given you a warning about this, if you dive
into the warnings.

The `clr` missing in the sensitivity list is not that visible if `clk` is
running, but if your current test bench only tries `clr` so far, it may be the
reason that you do not see any changes of `Q`.